# How to parse the hashed arguments (with # instead of ?) in url in GAE with python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

I want to parse the access_token from the url which facebook login will redirect to. What I got is the following URL and I'd like to know how to parse it in Google App Engine (GAE).

> http://localhost:8080/web/#access_token=aaaa&expires_in=5423

I tried using `get`, `get_all` but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urlparse
access_token = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlsplit(url).fragment).get('access_token')
```

Comment: Thanks! but now the problem becomes that I can't get the whole url using self.request.url in GAE. All I got is the url before # mark...

Comment: @AustinHuang The fragment identifier isn't actually sent server side in a HTTP request; it's purely for client side enhancements, like jumping to an element in the page, or reading/writing it in javascript to store state